# base and derived classes

Tags: c#

If I have Person class which will handle all common properties

```
Person.cs

public class Person
{
   public FirstAndLastName {get; set;}
   public Health Health {get; set;}
   public Personality Personality {get; set;}
}
```

now I will need Player objects and later on different types of players (soccerPlayer, bballplayer, etc.) Since player is a person can I use this approach

```
Player.cs
public class Player:Person
{
   public Sport Sport {get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to implement some sport based player unique properties like: in basketball alley up , or volley shoot in football (soccer). You've got the pic.

```
Basketball.cs
public class Basketball:Player
{
   public int AlleyUpLevel {get; set;}
}
```

Question: is this proper way of creating base and derived classes, should my basketball player have access to all properties defined in Person class ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way to create base and derived classes. Because your class `Basketball` inherits from `Player` which inherits from `Person`, `Basketball` will  indeed have access to everything defined in `Person` that is marked `public` or `protected`. Anything marked `private` will not be accessible to inheriting classes. Also keep in mind that in the case of many constructs such as fields and methods, the lack of an access modifier will default to a `private` access level.

Answer (score 2):

Since your properties are all `public`, *anyone*, not just those deriving from `Person`, has access to both getting and setting the value of the property.

You could consider making the setter `private` or `protected`, as in

```
public Personality Personality { get; protected set; }
```

The keyword `protected` means "only access from the containing class and from classes deriving from the containing class". On the other hand `private` means "only access from the containing class/struct".